# Creating and routing new pages in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am new to Svelte and I wanted to know how to open new pages using a button. For example in html you create either an action:

```
<form action="/route" method="post">
```

or create a function that opens a page:

```
<button onclick="openNewPage()">NEWPAGE</button>

<script>
  function openNewPage() {
      // Redirect to the new page
      window.location.href = '/NEWPAGE';
  }
</script>
```

and you redirect to another page. However, I dont know how to do that in the case of Svelte. I tried things as Modal but its not the same as redirecting to a new page.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add an "about" page as an example.

1. Create the page

- In your `src/routes` folder, create a folder with the name of the route to which you'd like to redirect.

  - Your folder would be called `about`, and the resulting structure would be: `src/routes/about`
  - In that folder, add a file called `+page.svelte`

```
src/
   |- routes/
      |- +page.svelte <- displayed @ localhost:xxxx/
      |- about/
         |- +page.svelte <- displayed @ localhost:xxxx/about
```

2. Redirecting to newly created route

- Use a method of `href`; here, let's use `<a></a>`

  - `<a href="/about">About Page</a>`

For a button, you can use `window.location.href` as follows:

```
<script>
    function handleClick() {
        window.location.href = "/about";
    }
</script>

<li>
    <button on:click={() => {handleClick()}}>
        About
    </button>
</li>
```

See: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/pages

Comment: thanks, this is really helpful! I did not see the tutorial

Comment: Just a side note, if you're redirecting to a new page an anchor tag is your best bet. That's what it's whole purpose is and you don't need js.